# It's this possible? - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I will like to create a policy resource depending on how many projects are described. Also, the policy must be different between these projects, for example, I have this far:

```
projects = ["project1", "project2"]
projects_resources = ["project1/X", "project1/Y", "project2/X", "project2/Y"]
```

data source:

```
data "template_file" "project_policy" {
  template = file("${path.module}/project_policy.tpl")
  vars = {
    projects_resources = join(",", var.projects_resources)
  }
}
```

project_policy.tpl:

```
...
"Resource": [
                %{ for projects_resources in slice(split(",", projects_resources), 0, length(split(",", projects_resources))-1) }
                    "arn:aws:...${projects_resources}}",
                %{ endfor }
                %{ for projects_resources in slice(split(",", projects_resources), length(split(",", projects_resources))-1, length(split(",", projects_resources))) }
                    "arn:aws:...${projects_resources}}"
                %{ endfor }
```

policy resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policies_projects" {
  count = length(var.projects)
  name = "policy_${var.projects[count.index]}"
  policy = data.template_file.policy_projects.rendered
}
```

**Current Outcome:**

policy_proyect1 and policy_proyect2 created with:

```
"Resource": 
                    "arn:aws:...proyect1/X",
                    "arn:aws:...proyect1/Y",
                    "arn:aws:...proyect2/X",
                    "arn:aws:...proyect2/Y"
```

---

what I would like to achieve:

policy_proyect1 with:

```
"Resource": 
                    "arn:aws:...proyect1/X",
                    "arn:aws:...proyect1/Y",
```

policy_proyect2 with:

```
"Resource": 
                    "arn:aws:...proyect2/X",
                    "arn:aws:...proyect2/Y",
```

I don't know if there is a way to create 2 rendered files for each policy in which only the values that correspond to the projects are passed as arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your current outcome? Any errors?

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question with properly formatted code blocks, rather then adding code in comments.

Comment: Okey @Marcin, sorry about that. Added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new local map and then use that for the template:

```
variable "projects" {
  default = ["project1", "project2"]
}

variable "projects_resources" {
  default = ["project1/X", "project1/Y", "project2/X", "project2/Y", "project2/Z"]
}

locals {
    
    proj_res_map = {for p in var.projects:
                    p => [for v in var.projects_resources : v if length(regexall("${p}.*", v)) > 0]
                   }
}
```

which gives:

```
proj_res_map = {
  "project1" = [
    "project1/X",
    "project1/Y",
  ]
  "project2" = [
    "project2/X",
    "project2/Y",
    "project2/Z",
  ]
}
```

Then use it:

```
data "template_file" "project_policy" {
  for_each = local.proj_res_map
  template = file("${path.module}/project_policy.tpl")
  vars = {
    projects_resources = join(",", each.value)
  }
}
```

Then `iam_policies_projects` probably will also need to be adjusted to account for for_each in template_file:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policies_projects" {
  for_each = local.proj_res_map
  name = "policy_${each.key}"
  policy = data.template_file.policy_projects[each.key].rendered
}
```

Comment: Looks amazing. Now I'm trying to adapt this code with the "real" one. You are correct, I got errors from iam_policies_projects. I could replace that count with the for_each = local.ecr_res_map to create resources in line with main values?? (more resources are being created with that count, changing it would make the code cleaner).

Comment: @naeroy Thanks. I updated answer with possible changes to `iam_policies_projects`.

Comment: Hmm, for_each says that the value it's unsuitable (ask for a map or set of strings). I trying to do something with toset and similar. Just for more info, the values come from an "above module" passed to arguments to this one module (a var.tf file contains variables with type = list(string)).

Comment: @naeroy Just use `for_each = local.proj_res_map` as in the updated answer.

Comment: ey @marcin, I got a lot of errors but from the other resources in the code. 
After spending some time with the code (definitely count has been replaced by this great map) I can say that it **WORKS PERFECTLY**. You are some kind of terraform god, hmm?
I definitely have to learn "for" and "maps" well, many possibilities can be achieved...
Thanks again!

Comment: @naeroy Thanks and no problem. You can always make new questions if you encounter new issues.